# Is there a way to reformat only modified code in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I only see the option to reformat the whole file. I know that Eclipse gives you the option to reformat only edited lines.

Comment: No, the more efficient option is reformat only src directory

Comment: Have you tried highlighting and then running Code -> Reformat Code?